# Arduino over /dev/ttyACM0 recognized but on group tty instead dialout. IDE fails to open the serial console

Tags: 16.04, usb, permissions, tty, arduino

I have plugged my arduino over the usb port and is recognized in `/dev/ttyACM0` port according to my `dmesg`:

```
[ 3269.509330] cdc_acm 1-6:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[ 3312.346228] usb 1-6: USB disconnect, device number 6
[ 3329.402161] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[ 3329.532105] usb 1-6: New USB device found, idVendor=2341, idProduct=0001
[ 3329.532114] usb 1-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=220
[ 3329.532120] usb 1-6: Product: Arduino Uno
[ 3329.532126] usb 1-6: Manufacturer: Arduino (www.arduino.cc)
[ 3329.532131] usb 1-6: SerialNumber: 6493234363835111B171
[ 3329.532394] usb 1-6: ep 0x82 - rounding interval to 1024 microframes, ep desc says 2040 microframes
[ 3329.533486] cdc_acm 1-6:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
```

But id I perform an `ls -l /dev/ttyACM0` is is shown in group `tty` instead of group `dialout`:

```
$ ls -l /dev/ttyACM0
crw--w---- 1 root tty 166, 0 Μάι  10 16:06 /dev/ttyACM0
```

As a result:

1. I get the following error when I try to open the serial console in Arduino IDE:

   > Error opening serial port '/dev/ttyACM0'. Try consulting the documentation at http://playground.arduino.cc/Linux/All#Permission
2. The `screen /dev/ttyACM0` command shows nothing.

Do you know how I will fix that or make when arduino is plugged in to set it into a different port as group `dialout` eg. `/dev/arduino0`?

**Ps** My user is in group `dialout` as `groups` command shows:

```
pcmagas adm tty uucp dialout cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare docker lxd wireshark
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes if you have put a service to allocate the port is is impossible to send or send data to the arduino. In order to do that disable any service that allocate the required USB port with the following command set:

```
sudo systemctl stop serial-getty@ttyACM0
sudo systemctl disable serial-getty@ttyACM0
```

Usually the common suspect is the service `serial-getty` in case you play with other boards (such as raspberry pi).

Further answers can be found over: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=546660.msg3726479#new